# Ngnix not matching location adress

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core, hosting, single-page-application

I have problem with Nginx + .Net core. I'm using default nginx configuration on only location block with "/" any other location blocks like "/api" doesn't works. Here is my configuration file

```
location  /api{ 
        proxy_pass https://localhost:5002/api/;
}

location  /auth
{  
        proxy_pass https://localhost:5002/auth/; 
}

location  /
 {
         proxy_pass https://localhost:5002/;   #home adress of spa app
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are specifying a URI at the end of the proxy pass which means the location will be appended to the URI as well. Check this examples:

```
www.site.com/api -> http://localhost:5002/api/api

www.site.com/auth -> http://localhost:5002/auth/auth
```

Instead, don't provide the URI in the locations so the path matches. Like this:

```
location  /api { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5002;
}

location  /auth {  
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5002; 
}

location  / {
         proxy_pass https://localhost:5002/;   #home adress of spa app
}
```

So now the URI ends up like this.

```
www.site.com/api -> http://localhost:5002/api/

www.site.com/auth -> http://localhost:5002/auth
```

PD.- check the https:// schema in your locations, do you really need it? Use http, I don't think you have SSL enabled for that port.